# Backend refreshing every time there is a new page load T3 stack

Tags: reactjs, next.js, backend, trpc.io, t3

So I have a T3 stack app in which `/src/server/api/routers/RouterX.ts` contains some info in an array that I have to maintain, but what happens is, every time there is a new page loaded, the server and client recompiles and I lose the data that was supposed to be maintained in the backend.
The following happens every time a new page is being loaded in the browser, for example I want to load `/WaitingRoom`

```
- wait compiling /WaitingRoom...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 231 ms (638 modules)
```

This `compiled client and server successfully` refreshes the variables in `RouterX.ts`. How would I fix this?

My `package.json` has

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "postinstall": "npx prisma generate --schema=prisma/schema.prisma ",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "start": "next start"
  }
```

and I'm using `npm run dev`

However, once I've loaded `/WaitingRoom` and I want to load it back again, then the server doesn't get compiled again.
How do I make my data stay persistent/stop the server from recompiling like this?